# How to disable Bootstrap 3 mobile responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I was commenting these code at bootstrap.css and my page is now not responsive. But my navbar still responsive. how to disable that?

```
/*@media (min-width: 768px) {
      .container {
        width: 750px;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .container {
        width: 970px;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px;
      }*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap made a `non-responsive.css` template to disable responsiveness for your template. Take a look at this documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive

But I see you want to do it your own way, so you could try this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container, .navbar {
        width: 750px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container, .navbar {
        width: 970px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container, .navbar {
        width: 1170px !important;
    }
}
```

Note that the code above will only apply to the classes `container` and `navbar`. There are other components/classes that should have static widths and heights. So I would recommend you to take a look at the example above.

Comment: i copied the non-responsive.css and it was totally works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Follow `Bootstrap's` official [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive).